# How to setup WebRTC for Azure

Tags: windows, azure, webrtc

I have azure subscription. I want to know that how can one setup WebRTC on azure, noticing that it needs node.js and other plugins.

I am using [WebRTC example](http://www.webrtc.org/demo) as a startup project.

I want to know how can I make the use of its code, make it work and use its source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the source files. Use a local git repository and after that push to a Windows Azure Web Site:

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/tutorials/create-a-website-(mac)/?fb=pt-br